# Create a SQL with dump of view definition - Order view to avoid dependencies problem

Tags: postgresql, view, dump, database-backups

I need to create a script to drop and re-create views of a PostgreSQL Database with dependency order

I have tried with this python code:

```
# Copyleft ....
import os,sys,shutil,re,glob, getopt
import datetime
#import ogr

#open PostGIS connection
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='XXXXX', port=5432, user='XXXXX', password='XXXXXX', host='XXXXXXX')


# Open a cursor to perform database operations
curr = conn.cursor()

conn.autocommit = True


#create the log file
f1=open('./log_cambio_CRS.txt', 'w')


#create the backup SQL file
ora=datetime.datetime.now()
ora_file=ora.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
nomefile='{0}_backup_viste_SIT2017.sql'.format(ora_file)
f2=open(nomefile, 'w')





#select
sql: str = 'SELECT t.table_schema, t.table_name, t.view_definition, row_number() over() as rowid ' \
      'FROM information_schema.views t ' \
      'where table_schema not in (\'gdo\', \'information_schema\', \'pg_catalog\', \'cron\', \'public\') ' \
      'order by rowid desc;'

print(sql)
curr.execute(sql)

for result in curr:
    schema=result[0]
    table=result[1]
    definition=result[2]

    f2.write('CREATE OR REPLACE {0}.{1} AS\n {2}'.format(schema,table,definition))
    f2.write('\n\n-- **************************************************\n\n')

curr.close


# new query to drop views - the order need to be the reverse
curr = conn.cursor()
#select
sql: str = 'SELECT t.table_schema, t.table_name ' \
      'FROM information_schema.views t ' \
      'where table_schema not in (\'gdo\', \'information_schema\', \'pg_catalog\', \'cron\',\'public\');'

print(sql)
curr.execute(sql)

for result in curr:
    schema=result[0]
    table=result[1]
    drop_sql='DROP VIEW {0}.{1};'.format(schema,table);
    print(drop_sql)
    #curr.execute(drop_sql)

curr.close


curr = conn.cursor()
```

The problem is related to the query

```
SELECT t.table_schema, t.table_name, t.view_definition, row_number() over() as rowid   
FROM information_schema.views t 
where table_schema not in ('gdo', 'information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'cron', 'public')
order by rowid desc;
```

I'm not sure the order to create the views is correct. For example it is possible that the first view of the SQL depend on a view which is not yet created, so the SQL will not works!

Answer (score 1):

I partially solved (only for DB without restoring) and post the answer for people need the same solution:

The solution is to use the **pg_class** table which contains the **relfilenode** field.

The SQL backup script is created ordering the views using the following rule:

```
order by relfilenode;
```

while I drop the views ordering them in the opposite way:

```
order by relfilenode DESC;
```

An example of query used to obtain the view definitions is the following:

```
SELECT t.table_schema, t.table_name, t.view_definition,
row_number() over() as rowid , p.relfilenode 
FROM information_schema.views t, pg_class p 
where table_schema not in ('gdo', 'information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'cron', 'public') 
and p.relname=t.table_name
order by p.relfilenode;
```

I hope it can be useful, but we need a better solution using **pg_depend** and/or **pg_history**

Any examples?

Comment: A smart idea, which will probably work for you. I just wanted to remark that `relfilenode` originally is the same as `oid`, the "object id", and is created using a 4-byte unsigned integer counter. At some point this counter can wrap around, and views that are created later might get a lower `oid` (and `relfilenode`) than older ones. The bullet-proof technique would be a recursive query using `pg_depend`, where dependencies between objects are registered. But that would be way more complicated.

Comment: you are right @LaurenzAlbe .. have you an example of the recursive query using *pg_depend*?

Comment: No, and unfortunately I don't have the time to come up with one right now - you need `pg_depend` and `pg_rewrite` (where the query of the view is stored).

Comment: sorry but I do not understand how [pg_depend](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/catalog-pg-depend.html) can be used to order view.

Comment: Yes, it is complicated. The table contains dependencies between objects. A view has a dependency on its rewrite rule, and the rewrite rule has a dependency on the base object. The base object can again be a view; this is where recursion sets in.